# How to bind images to gridview in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How to bind images to a GridView in MvvmCross where all the images are in a folder of android mobile. 
I am using C#, Xamarin Android and MvvmCross.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364197/using-mvxgridview-in-mvvmcross) didn't help much.